# Google Developer Console app releases section - what is the "Internal Test" track used for?

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

google play developer console has a near channel called "**internal test**". it is the last one in the list and i took a image of it below.  how does it compare with alpha channel ? im not understanding its usecase ?  seems your allowed 100 users.

I tried looking for documentation but i only see that it makes the app available faster. is that the prime benefit ?
[image]

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: ok. i was actually thinking it would be distributed faster. but from the docs i cant tell if the  propagation time is smaller in comparison to the other distribution channels.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings , so all needed to enable app to be accessible via Opt-in URL is just to Create a release with built APK? Or some ore steps is needed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is correct, the Internal test track primary advantage is that APKs published to this track are available to testers within seconds, instead of up to several hours for Alpha or Beta.

Also, Internal testers can access app versions that are not otherwise available to other tracks users due to various restrictions such as device exclusions.

Finally, Internal testers do not have to pay to acquire the test version of the app, if the app is paid.

The internal test track is designed for internal testing use cases.

Comment: this is to confirm i got the build very quickly after posting it to internal test channel. within a minute it was available. the funny thing is the google play store web page still showed the previous version but when i downloaded it it was the correct version i was expecting. thanks.

Comment: @j2emanue, how did you do it? I have uploaded the app more than 2 hours ago and the damn Opt-in URL is still empty...

Comment: you need to put in  the email addresss of those you want to access it.

Comment: Did you say seconds? Not sure this is the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457089/pending-publication-for-internal-test-more-than-12-hours ?

Comment: It will take seconds if your app is already in the 'published' state (i.e. it is not your first roll out to a track).