# Pending Publication for Internal test more than 12 Hours

Tags: android

I don't think it should last more than that.

We followed all the guidance of google, sometimes there were secret hints that we should have found but now, 
it stuck there.

it's not even in alpha test but it's in Internal test.

Searching for 15 minutes to find release button and then clicking it again creates another disappointment.:(

It becomes a frustration to release an app at least for me.

İt s not clear for people first time doing that.

So I should ask you are there any hidden secret to publish an ap to internal testing?

Comment: You do know that you can distribute Android apps to cooperating users like internal testers without going through any formal app store, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions about app distribution channels are considered to be off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @ChrisStratton the only reason most of us test via the store is because of IAP

Comment: @ChrisStratton I didn't know that. How do you distribute it?

Comment: Email.  Web server with the appropriate MIME type hiding behind a sign in page?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Please let us know if this is true for testing the apps with in-app purchases. How can we test the in-app purchases before google approving our internal track test?

Answer (score 10):

as mentioned in this linked comment [Pending Publication for Internal test more than 12 Hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457089/pending-publication-for-internal-test-more-than-12-hours#comment85917887_49457089) this is kinda off topic but for those who want an idea of what to expect I found:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

> Note: If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up
>   to **48 hours** for your app's internal test to be available

.

[image: wait 48 hours for first time publication]

**Update 2019-03-11:** Google updated the page from "48 hours" to "a few hours"

> After publishing an open, closed, or internal test for the first time, it may take a few hours for your test link to be available to testers. If you publish additional changes, they may take several hours to be available for testers.

Comment: A few hours.. doesn't that defeat the point of internal test?

Comment: Tips -> When should I use an internal test? -> Note: If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up to 48 hours for your app's internal test to be available.  it still shows 48 hours..June 10th 2019

Comment: as of July, 12 2019 _Note: If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up to **48 hours** for your app's internal test to be available._

Comment: first they say we can roll out apps within minutes for internal testing... and then they make us wait forever

Comment: @davee44 it's 7 days AND more. They don't even tell the reason. And this is all for us testing in-app purcahses. Has anyone a suggestion to test in-app purchases for the first time without this long waiting list?

Comment: The whole Google Play Console experience is truly a child of neglect by their engineers and product team. And yet it does nothing to stem the tide of malicious apps on the Play store.

Comment: In my experience the review process seems to take a couple of days now, even for internal testing. They mention as much in the banner as well now.

Comment: Some BS by Google, we can't even test IAP until it's approved.

Answer (score 2):

For some google accounts the first publish can take 3 days or more!

> For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how long this should take. We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period of at least three days between submitting your app and going live.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282

Comment: That makes sense for the production track, but not for the internal test.

Comment: I agree. Sadly I received this message for internal test.

Comment: @alichur how much time did it take for it?

Comment: For me about 24 hours, this was 6 years ago though

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the Pre-launch report in your email, you should be good to go. The Pre-launch report lists all the crashes and security vulnerabilities in your app, and considering the number of updates the Play Store receives in a day, I'm not surprised there's a bottleneck there. In my experience, it takes about 3-4 hours for this "fast" update to become available, even though it's not a new app.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who, like me, doesn't want my users to wait hours or days to test app updates, here's what you can do:

1. Use Android Studio to build an APK.
2. Upload the APK to the cloud and give access to your testers. In my case, I used Google Drive.
3. The first time you download the app, Google will warn you about downloading apps that are not from Google Play, but will let you do it anyway by setting a switch to "on". Do that.
4. When you try to open the downloaded APK, you'll get another warning about the app being from an unknown publisher. Scroll down a bit and click on the link "Open anyway".

That's all there is to it. I tested this just now and it works as described.