# Google play stuck on "internal testing"

Tags: google-play, expo

I deployed and published my app to the Google Play Console 6 days ago and the status is stuck on "internal testing". Do I need to do something? Or how much time does it take to publish the app?[image]

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457089/pending-publication-for-internal-test-more-than-12-hours/52922183

Answer (score 3):

**For some google accounts the first publish can take 3 days or more and If you're publishing an app for the first time, it may take up to 48 hours for your app's internal test to even just be available. Also, After publishing an open, closed, or internal test for the first time, it may take a few hours for your test link to be available to testers. If you publish additional changes, they may take several hours to be available for testers.**

> > For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly
> > review your app(s) to help better protect users. You’ll receive a
> > notification on your app's Dashboard about how long this should take.
> > We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period
> > of at least three days between submitting your app and going live.
>
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282

**This may also help**

> I managed to fix this by enabling the internal app sharing option on
> the play store account I wanted to test the app before accessing the
> link. Just open your playstore, click on settings, enable developer
> mode (by tapping seven times on the Play Store Version) and then
> enable the internal app sharing.
>
> If it doesn't work, you could change the permissions on "Manage
> testers (on your internal test playstore console)" from "Restrict
> access to email lists" to "Anyone you shared the link with can
> download", after accessing the link for the first time you should have
> access to it even if you switch back to "Restrict access to email
> lists".

Comment: So i must to put emails to internal testers?  I dont understand and i dont have people to test this

Comment: No, the first idea was more directed to your question, but the second part was a little bit extra sort of ‘just incase’ you were using internal testers etc and you hadn’t specified. I was trying to cover as many answers to the question as possible to try and give you the right one. Indeed try all options but it doesnt mean every option is necessary and as seen now, the second one can be ignored as it does not help you. - hope that helps. Enjoy the new year

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have published your app on the Internal Testing Track instead of the Production track. That is why it is not published.

To publish it on the Release track go to "Release" > "Production" > "Releases" > "Create new Release". Now add your apk/app bundle and publish it. It should get reviewed and published within a few days.

Comment: I did it..before week

Comment: Add screenshots of your Production track